# Gulp and phantomjs

Tags: phantomjs, gulp

I'm trying to run automatic test with gulp. Everything works fine but I don't now how to close PhantomJS after codeception has finished.
My gulp.js file looks like this

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var connect = require('gulp-connect-php');
var shell = require('gulp-shell');
var codecept = require('gulp-codeception');

gulp.task('webserver', function() {

    connect.server({
      base : './public'
    });
});

gulp.task('phantom', shell.task(['phantomjs.exe --webdriver=4444']));

gulp.task('codecept', function() {
    gulp.src('./tests/*.php').pipe(codecept());
});

gulp.task('tests', ['phantom', 'codecept']);
```

Is there way to stop Phantom after all tests are done or better way to lunch Phantom?

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me under PhantomJS v2.0:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var gutil = require('gulp-util');
var codecept = require('gulp-codeception');

gulp.task('codecept', function(done) {
   runInPhantomJs(function() {
       return gulp.src('./tests/*.php').pipe(codecept());
   }, done);
});

function runInPhantomJs(fn, done) {
    var args = [ '--webdriver=4444' ],
    phantomjsProcess = childProcess.spawn('phantomjs', args),
    completed = false;

    phantomjsProcess.stdout.on('data', function(data) {
        if (data.toString().indexOf('running on port') >= 0) {
            fn().on('end', function() {
                completed = true;
                phantomjsProcess.kill();
            });
        }
    });
    phantomjsProcess.stderr.on('data', function(data) {
        gutil.log(gutil.colors.red(data));
    });
    phantomjsProcess.on('close', function(code) {
        if (code && !completed) {
            return done(new Error('phantomjs failed with code: ' + code + '\n' +
               'Check that port 4444 is free and that there are no other ' +
               'instances of phantomjs running.'));
        }
        done();
    });
}
```